# Internet and server connectivity through a switch?

Tags: router, ethernet, switch

I have two separate connections. Input one is an internet connection coming straight from my router via ethernet - the second input is a standalone server coming from another ethernet. Both are going into a switch. Can I receive both signals through one Ethernet port from the switch to my machine?

I've attached an image for a visual reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a normal consumer-level 4 or 8 port switch -

***Anything* connected to the switch can see and talk to *anything else* on the switch unless that thing firewalls the connection.**

But keep in mind:

Your router has 2 IPs

- an internal ("LAN") IP

  - this is the "default gateway"
  - most consumer routers don't have a single LAN port but have a built in "LAN Switch"
  - if your router is like most other consumer routers, it's running a small DHCP server, listening for DHCP requests on the LAN IP.
  - devices on the switch talk to this IP's DHCP server, and get an IP from the router, and are told the default gateway as well.
- an external IP ("WAN")

  - this is your device's "Internet" port.
  - your ISP runs a DHCP server of its own and the WAN interface takes the IP provided by your ISP's DHCP server.

The internal "default gateway" is visible on the switch (and has to be if you want things on that switch to reach the Internet).

The LAN and WAN IP are not directly connected or on the same switch internally, therefore:

- The WAN connection is NOT visible on the switch

  - so it cannot be directly accessed by things on the switch.
  - If something wants to reach something beyond the WAN IP it must "go through" the router.
  - The router does NAT which allows all devices on that switch to share the WAN IP.
- WAN DHCP won't "leak" into your LAN and vice versa (unless you really really horribly hack and misconfigure the box).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear.  If you mean "if I plug my PC in, can I see both devices and interact with them", the answer is yes.

If you mean can I see all traffic flowing through the switch on my PC, the answer is you will (a) need a management port which enables mirroring all data to it and (b) this will only work for data which traverses the switch you are connected into, so not data only flowing between devices on the second switch - assuming you have 2 switches which is unclear.   [ An alternative would be to hack the way your network works and convert your computer into a router using vlans etc - messy, and, I suspect not what you are asking ]

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can.

Using the visual reference in practise, you can connect to the internet and the server, but you may run into configuration issues. (subnet, ip ranges, etc.)

To avoid this, you should drop the network switch and start using the router that has been provided by your ISP (the box you use to connect to the internet) by connecting the three computers plus the server (assuming you have four ethernet ports, all three computers take up three ports and the server only takes one port.)